# Angular - get synchronously from Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise

I want to print history of products. I have an id of product in ActivatedRoute.params. In ngOnInit method I have to get all history of product and assign to variable. Then I want to map product to productHistory, because I want to have last version with history toghether. But the problem is with getting history. Method to getting history return Promise and I cannot get length of productsHistory when I use this property and I get undefined. How can I get this property after loading from service?

I want to execute method after execution getHistory().

My code:

ProductService.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

// rest imports

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

    // URL to web api
    private projectsUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/products';

    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getHistory(id: number): Promise<ProductHistory[]> {
        const url = `${this.projectsUrl}/projectId/${id}`;
        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as ProductHistory[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    handleError() {
        //...
        // implementation is irrelevant
    }
}
```

ProductHistoryComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { ProductService } from './product.service';

import { ProductHistory } from './product-history';
import { Product } from './model/product';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
    selector: 'product-history',
    templateUrl: './product-history.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './product-history.component.css' ]
})
export class ProductHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

    auditProducts: ProductHistory[] = new Array<ProductHistory[]>();    
    selectedProduct: ProductHistory;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location,
        private productService: ProductService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let id: number = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

        this.productService.getHistory(id)
            .then(history => this.historyProducts = history);

        this.productService.getProduct(id)
            .then(product => {
                let lastVersion: ProductHistory = this.createLastVersion(product);
                this.auditProducts.push(lastVersion);
            });
    }

    onSelect(ProductHistory: ProductHistory): void {
        this.selectedProduct = ProductHistory;
        this.compare(this.selectedProduct);
    }

    goBack(): void {
        this.location.back();
    }

    compare(history: ProductHistory): void {
        let previous: ProductHistory;
        if (history.changeNumber != null && history.changeNumber > 1) {
            previous = this.historyProducts[history.changeNumber - 2];
            if (typeof previous != 'undefined') {
                this.setPreviousDiffsFalse(previous);
                if (previous.name !== history.name) {
                    history.nameDiff = true;
                }
                if (previous.price !== history.price) {
                    history.priceDiff = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    createLastVersion(product: Product): ProductHistory {
        let lastVersionProduct: ProductHistory = new ProductHistory();
        lastVersionProduct.id = this.historyProducts.length + 1;
        lastVersionProduct.name = product.name;
        lastVersionProduct.price = product.price;
        lastVersionProduct.changeNumber = this.historyProducts[this.historyProducts.length - 1].changeNumber + 1;
        return lastVersionProduct;
    }

    setPreviousDiffsFalse(previous: ProductHistory): void {
        previous.nameDiff = false;
        previous.priceDiff = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot get a value synchronously from a promise any more than you get an apple from an orange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run it synchronously, you have to wait  for each promise to return a result before you can do something with that result. The normal way to do this is to nest code inside `then` blocks when using promises. Alternatively you can also use `async/await` with the latest version of typescript and you only have to change your `component` code as you are already returning the `Promise` type from your service. This makes code easier to read (IMO) although the emitted javascript code will still use function/callback nesting (*unless you are targeting es7 I believe, maybe someone will correct or confirm this*).

```
// note the use of async and await which gives the appearance of synchronous execution
async ngOnInit() {
    let id: number = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    const history = await this.productService.getHistory(id);
    this.historyProducts = history;

    const product = await this.productService.getProduct(id);
    let lastVersion: ProductHistory = this.createLastVersion(product);
    this.auditProducts.push(lastVersion);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using observables instead of promises ... but to answer your question, you just need to perform the second request *after* the first is received. Something like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let id: number = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.productService.getHistory(id)
        .then(history => {
               this.historyProducts = history);

               this.productService.getProduct(id)
                     .then(product => {
                         let lastVersion: ProductHistory = this.createLastVersion(product);
                         this.auditProducts.push(lastVersion);
        });
     }
}
```

I just moved the second request *within* the then of the first request. NOTE: I did not syntax check this.